# How to add a back button to a custom made UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, back-button

I made a custom UINavigationBar using constraints. I am having trouble adding a back button to it. I could just make a UI Button and layer it on top, but I don't want to do that unless I have to.

Here is the relevant code used.

```
let navBar: UINavigationBar = {


    let myNav = UINavigationBar()

    myNav.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    return myNav

    }()


func setUpNavBarView(){


self.navBar.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
self.navBar.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor as NSLayoutAnchor<NSLayoutYAxisAnchor>).isActive = true
self.navBar.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
self.navBar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true

   self.navBar.barTintColor = UIColor.red

    self.navBar.isTranslucent = false


}
```

Comment: Do you have a previous view controller in the navigation controller?

Comment: I do not, is it your thinking that this will force it to add a back button since the previous viewController would be the first in the stack?

Comment: I believe so, by adding a previous view controller to the navigation controller, it should have a back button defaulting to the name of the previous view controller, or Back if nil.

Comment: I'm checking right now, but I am not sure if just adding a navigation controller in the way that I did will actually fix it.

Comment: It's not just adding a navigation controller, in the view with the navBar, there needs to be a previous view controller.

Comment: There is, but I use a UIButton to send the user to the view with the nav bar.

Comment: you can add a back button manually by setting a UIBarButtonItem to your view controllers left navigationItem. Then call whatever transition you need to from the UIBarButtonItem target.

Comment: I've been trying to do that, but I am not sure how to do that. The function call won't show up. I tried self.navBar."insert proper code here" and it hasn't been working. I don't have access to the method.

Comment: check my answer, you don't set it on the navBar. Set it directly on the navigationItem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lazy var backButton: UIBarButtonItem = {
  let button = UIBarButtonItem(image: "Image", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(backButtonTapped))
  return button
}()

navigationItem.setLeftBarButton(backButton, animated: false)

func backButtonTapped() {
   //Do transition here
}
```

Comment: do i put navigationItem.setLeftBarButton(backButton, animated: false) in viewDidLoad?

Comment: technically you can do it anytime in the lifecycle of VC but if you want it there when the view appears then yes, viewDidLoad is a good spot.

Comment: I tested your code and there were no errors, but the button did not show up.  I put a test image in where it says "Image". I am going to play around a bit with the viewController

Comment: make sure you still have the view controller embeded inside the nav controller. You can also use the barButton that is initialized with a title inside of an image.